# Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json"

Tags: http, dart, flutter

```
Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json','authorization':'Basic c3R1ZHlkb3RlOnN0dWR5ZG90ZTEyMw=='};

var response = await post(Urls.getToken,
        headers: headers,
        body: {"grant_type":"password","username":"******","password":"*****","scope":"offline_access"},
      );
```

When I execute this I am unable to recieve data and the error thrown is

Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json"

Comment: try - `body: json.encode({"grant_type":"password","username":"******","password":"*****","scope":"offline_access"}),`

Comment: Watch out that you have post also your `username/password` even if they could be of a test user, this is not a good practice...

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You need to wrap the body in `jsonEncode`.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json','authorization':'Basic c3R1ZHlkb3RlOnN0dWR5ZG90ZTEyMw=='};
final msg = jsonEncode({"grant_type":"password","username":"******","password":"*****","scope":"offline_access"});

var response = await post(Urls.getToken,
               headers: headers,
               body: msg,
            );
```

Comment: Thanks! At first I didn't see the difference between your answer and the question, but now I see that the key is to wrap the map literal in a jsonEncode

Answer (score 40):

Use `jsonEncode` to wrap your body `object`.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

var headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'authorization':'Basic c3R1ZHlkb3RlOnN0dWR5ZG90ZTEyMw=='
};

final body = {
    'username':'foo',
    'password':'pass123'
}

var response = await post(
    Urls.getToken,
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonEncode(body), // use jsonEncode()
);
```

**Why `jsonEncode`?**

***body***: It can be a HTML, JSON or XML, etc. This mean is we need to send/recive data in that perticular format. You can set this in `content-type` header its default value is `text/plain`.

As you set the `content-type` header to `JSON` you must have to pass a "valid" JSON as the body. But you are passing `Map<String, String>` as the body, which obviously throws an error.

**So to solve this issue you need to change (or `encode`) your `Map<String, String>` data to `JSON` data.**

Best way to do this is to use `jsonEncode` function.

Answer (score 3):

had similar issue with http library...changed for dio 2.1.0 and the problem with headers is gone.

jsonEncode(body) didn't do the trick, because the docs say:

> Sends an HTTP POST request with the given headers and body to the given
> URL, which can be a [Uri] or a [String].

> [body] sets the body of the request. It can be a [String], a [List]
> or a [Map<String, String>]. If it's a String, it's encoded using
> [encoding] and used as the body of the request. The content-type of the
> request will default to "text/plain".

> If [body] is a List, it's used as a list of bytes for the body of the
> request.

> If [body] is a Map, it's encoded as form fields using [encoding]. The
> content-type of the request will be set to
> `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`; this cannot be overridden.
> [encoding] defaults to [utf8].

> For more fine-grained control over the request, use [send] instead.

```
Future<Response> post(url, {Map<String, String> headers, body, Encoding encoding});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<String,String> header = {'Content-Type':'application/json-patch+json','accept':'application/json'};
    final msg = jsonEncode({"username":"$emailorPhoneN","password":"$passwrod"});

    try {
      var response = await http.post(UrlConstants.loginUrl, headers: header, body: msg,
      ).timeout(Duration(seconds: httpDuration));
      var convert = json.decode(response.body);
      print('**********Data from server $convert');

      if (convert == null) {
        return null;
      } else {
        String token = convert['token'];

        if (token != null) {
          SignUpModel signUpModel = SignUpModel.fromJson(convert);
          return signUpModel;
        } else {
          //*** GET Error message from the API provider.....
          SignUpModel signUpModel = SignUpModel.fromJson(convert);
          return signUpModel;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, `jsonencode(body)` did not work.
This is worked for me instead:

```
body = json.encode(body);
http.post(Uri.parse(uri), headers: header, body: body);
```