# dart http give me 400 before send out request and response's body is blank string

Tags: dart, post

I am making POST request using `http` lib in Dart. After I wandering around former answers with no luck. Even [official doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data)

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<http.Response> createAlbum(String nameEN) {
  return http.post(
    'http://localhost:8000/api/products/',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'nameEN': nameEN,
    }),
  );
}
```

And I test with unittest like this

```dart
  testWidgets('POST request from offcial docs', (WidgetTester tester) async{
    final http.Response res = await createAlbum("Jordan");
    print(res.statusCode);
  });
```

**Attempt:**
PostmanApp can make request and get 201 in response. However, when I copy&paste the Dart code from it and test it does not work
I always get `400` and no request comes to `localhost:8000`

```dart
testWidgets('POST request from postman', (WidgetTester tester) async{
    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    var request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse('localhost:8000/api/products/'));
    request.body = '''{\n    "name_jp": "李天宝",\n    "name_en": "Sarit",\n    "description": "Developer",\n    "qty": 3,\n    "expiry": "2099-12-25",\n    "barcode": "549XXXYYYYYY",\n    "price": "{\\"bounds\\": \\"[)\\", \\"lower\\": \\"12\\", \\"upper\\": \\"6\\"}",\n    "medium_price": 60\n}''';
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(200);
      print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    }
    else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  });
```

**Problem**
Dart response returned to me is `400` and on the server side `request` has not been sent out to my `http://localhost:8000/api/products/`

**Question:**
What is the correct `POST` syntax?

**References:**

[HTTP POST with Json on Body - Flutter/Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278258/http-post-with-json-on-body-flutter-dart)

[Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849725/bad-state-cannot-set-the-body-fields-of-a-request-with-content-type-applicatio)

[Flutter FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671441/flutter-formatexception-unexpected-character-at-character-1)

[Http POST request with json content-type in dart:io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574740/http-post-request-with-json-content-type-in-dartio)

Answer (score 0):

You have non-ASCII characters.  Did you set the proper `; charset=UTF-8` in your Content-Type header?  Or even better, JSON doesn't understand non-ASCII unless you `\u` encode them.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I will post my answer and pitfall on my journey

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learnt here

1. Add `CORS` enable in `chrome`
2. `flutter run -d web`. Do not use `-d chrome`
3. Make request from cors enabled chrome by clicking. Do not use unittest!